# partial carraige return in python

Tags: python, nose, carriage-return

I'm trying to add prints inside nosetests run that show how much of the test has passes, but I do not want to use full carriage return.

It should look like:

my_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing 10%

my_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing 20%

...

my_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing 100%

my_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing ok

all in the same line.

I cannot use "\r" because it will override the entire line. I need a way to use some "partial carriage return" of a given number of letters.

How can I do it?

Comment: Wait, so you want a new line without actually printing a new line?

Answer (score 1):

You do know the test class and method since that's where you're printing the progress, so you can use `'\r'` and print the *prefix* alongside the completion degree

```
from sys import stderr
import time

for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    print('\rmy_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing: {} %'.format(i), end='', file=stderr)
    time.sleep(1)

print('\rmy_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing: ok  ', file=stderr)
```

---

If not, then you can probably use backspace `\010`:

```
from sys import stderr
import time

class BsPrinter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.previous_length = 0

    def output(self, msg):
        print('\010' * self.previous_length + msg, end='', file=stderr)
        self.previous_length = len(msg)

print('my_test_module.MyTestCase.test_somthing: ', end='', file=sys.stderr)
bs = BsPrinter()
for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    bs.output('{} %'.format(i))
    time.sleep(1)

bs.output('')
print('ok', file=stderr)
```

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @GioraGuttsait in that case you might consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may also choose to do:

```
import sys
import time

print("hello", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10)
print("\b\b\b\b\bworld", end="")
```

the '\b' is the backspace character.  That should allow you to back up and overwrite a partial line,  but I think just reprinting the whole line as in the other answer is easier and cleaner.